# Wordpress admin menu not showing

Tags: wordpress

I'm building my first Worpess plugin. But 'hammu dating' is not showing up in the 'settings' panel in the wp-admin. The plugin is activated in the 'plugin' panel. I followed the instructions from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus).

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'hammenu' );

function hammenu() {
    add_options_page( 'opties', 'Opties', 'manage-options', 'hd_menu_1', 'hammu_options' );
}

function hammu_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'No rights' ) );
    }
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<p>Nothing interesting here, yet</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Note: this is just a part of the plugin code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `add_options_page();` function carries wrong capability slug: `manage-options`
use `manage_options` instead.

Hope it helps!